# C# IndexOf (Read from resource.resx)

Tags: c#, text, resources, split, indexof

I created config file with some texts and this file i added to resource.resx. Now i created string for this text.

```
// String will be contains all texts from resource file
string TextFromResources = Resource.konfigurace;
```

TextFromResources - > View:

```
#################
# Settings
#################

RealmID = 1

#################
```

For next step i need use function "IndexOf".

```
int value = TextFromConfig.IndexOf("RealmID");
value = TextFromConfig.IndexOf('=');
value2 = TextFromConfig.IndexOf("/r/n");
RealmID = int.Parse(TextFromConfig.Substring(value, value2));
```

I need that realmID return me int value "1", but now its return me nothing. Please, can you help with my problem?

If index will be correctly so it will be return me value "1" nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the substring needs to start after `value`.  Here's a simplified version of your example that works for me:

```
var text = "RealmID = 1\r\n";
var value = text.IndexOf('=');
var value2 = text.IndexOf("\r\n", value);
var id = int.Parse(text.Substring(value + 1, value2 - value));
```

Also, I modified the `IndexOf` call for getting `value2` so that it searches for `"\r\n"` *after* the location of `'='`.

Another option is to use a regular expression to find the RealmID value.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"RealmID = (\d+)");
var match = regex.Match(text);
int realmID = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: i rewrite view. This is correctly visual for view file. But my script for index of still dont work.

Comment: Reges is not good for me now because i show you only one value in file what i need earn but in file is massive values

`var value = TextFromConfig.IndexOf("RealmID");
            value = TextFromConfig.IndexOf('=');
            var value2 = TextFromConfig.IndexOf("\r\n", value);
            RealmID = int.Parse(TextFromConfig.Substring(value + 1, value2 - value));`

Its return me this:

`RealmID 0 int
  value 1730 int
  value2 1733 int`

Comment: My problem is fixed. Thx for help.